# broadcasting value in list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I want to broadcast a value in

```
lst1=[{'a1':0,'a2':0,'a3':0,'a4':0,'a5':0},
 {'b1':0,'b2':0,'b3':0,'b4':0,'b5':0},
 {'c1':0,'c2':0,'c3':0,'c4':0,'c5':1} 
 ]
```

If the dictonary have 1 in it, then all the value in the dictionary will broadcast to 1
desire output would be

```
lst1=[{'a1':0,'a2':0,'a3':0,'a4':0,'a5':0},
 {'b1':0,'b2':0,'b3':0,'b4':0,'b5':0},
 {'c1':1,'c2':1,'c3':1,'c4':1,'c5':1}]
```

The problem is, we dont know the keys of the dictionary, the 'c1' or 'a1' will be random, but will always know to search for the last element of the dictionary, for example we always search the value of 'a5','b5' or 'c5'. Thank you for your answer

Works like a charm with Rakesh answer
However I have new datastructure, how i solve this

```
lst1=[[{'a1':'zz','lb':0},{'a2':'zz','lb':0},{'a3':'zz','lb':0}],
 [{'b1':'zz','lb':0},{'b2':'zz','lb':0},{'a3':'zz','lb':0}],
 [{'c1':'zz','lb':0},{'c2':'zzz','lb':0},{'c3':'zz','lb':1}]]
```

desired output

```
lst1=[[{'a1':'zz','lb':0},{'a2':'zz','lb':0},{'a3':'zz','lb':0}],
 [{'b1':'zz','lb':0},{'b2':'zz','lb':0},{'a3':'zz','lb':0}],
 [{'c1':'zz','lb':1},{'c2':'zzz','lb':1},{'c3':'zz','lb':1}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using a list comprehension with a dict comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
lst1=[{'a1':0,'a2':0,'a3':0,'a4':0,'a5':0}, {'b1':0,'b2':0,'b3':0,'b4':0,'b5':0}, {'c1':0,'c2':0,'c3':0,'c4':0,'c5':1}]

print([{k: 1 for k, v in i.items()} if 1 in i.values() else i for i in lst1])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'a4': 0, 'a5': 0},
 {'b1': 0, 'b2': 0, 'b3': 0, 'b4': 0, 'b5': 0},
 {'c1': 1, 'c2': 1, 'c3': 1, 'c4': 1, 'c5': 1}]
```

---

Edit as per comment

```
lst1=[[{'a1':'zz','lb':0},{'a2':'zz','lb':0},{'a3':'zz','lb':0}], [{'b1':'zz','lb':0},{'b2':'zz','lb':0},{'a3':'zz','lb':0}], [{'c1':'zz','lb':0},{'c2':'zzz','lb':0},{'c3':'zz','lb':1}]]
for elem in lst1:
    sync = False
    for i in elem:
        if i['lb'] == 1:
            sync = True
            break
    if sync:
        for i in elem:
            i['lb'] = 1

print(lst1)
```

**Output:**

```
[[{'a1': 'zz', 'lb': 0}, {'a2': 'zz', 'lb': 0}, {'a3': 'zz', 'lb': 0}],
 [{'b1': 'zz', 'lb': 0}, {'b2': 'zz', 'lb': 0}, {'a3': 'zz', 'lb': 0}],
 [{'c1': 'zz', 'lb': 1}, {'c2': 'zzz', 'lb': 1}, {'c3': 'zz', 'lb': 1}]]
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thank you for your answer, it works like a charm. However, I have another question. Turns out the datastructure is a little bit different.  I update my question, please help